# can we store multiple records with same key in memcache?

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I have two database tables, 1. Cities, 2. Details. 
'Details' table references 'cities' as foreign key. Now can I store data in memcache according to city (one key storing multiple records of details)? If yes, how should I make my key? If not, what's the best way to do it using memcache?

Answer (score 0):

DeNormalize - against the city ket store details from the city table AND the details table. That denormalization is common; though it comes with associated disadvantages of denormalization; primarily memory/space related.

If not, introduce a synthetic key; maintain city table as is with it's own key BUT store an additional key within city record. Store the data from details against this other key.  This comes with associated disadvantage of having to make two queries against memcache.

Comment: Can I do something like this?

    $key = md5("SELECT * FROM table where cityname='{$id}'");
   //echo $key;
  $get_result = array();
  $get_result = $memcache->get($key);

Will it return multiple record ?

Answer (score 0):

memcached is a plain key-value store, so there is no multi-associativity.
One possible solution is to store details by city through separator

```
<city>=<detail1>;<detail2>;
```

The downside of this approach - there is no way to check if `<city>` key already contains specific detail data on a server side.

The usual way is to create combined keys

```
<city>:<detail_id>=<detail>
```

But then, there is no way to get all details by the city.